Button to update the categorized renderer of layers in QGIS
In QGIS the empty layer "Symbology" has a categorized renderer that defines a color for each country. I want it to act as a global categorized renderer for several hundreds of layers and so I defined the button:
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction
from qgis.core import QgsProject,  QgsLayerTreeLayer, QgsLayerTreeGroup, QgsLayerTreeModel, QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.utils import iface

# Update the renderers of all 'SUP' layers with the Symbology layer renderer (country colors).
def handle_button_click():
    
    symbologyLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Symbology")[0]    
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    group = root.findGroup("SUP")
    
    for child in group.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
            layer = child.layer()
            layer.setRenderer(symbologyLayer.renderer())
            layer.triggerRepaint()

# Create an action for the toolbar button.
def add_button_to_toolbar():
    
    icon = QIcon("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Project\\Icons\\Symbology.png")
    custom_action = QAction(icon, "Update Symbology", iface.mainWindow())
    custom_action.triggered.connect(handle_button_click)
    
    # Add the action to the toolbar.
    iface.addToolBarIcon(custom_action)

# Run this function to add the button.
add_button_to_toolbar()

It correctly adds the button to the toolbar, and works sometimes without crashing QGIS with a Windows Fatal Access Violation.
How can I avoid crashes, or is there an alternate way to implement this behavior?

Renderers can’t be shared so you need to clone the renderer for each layer you want to attach it to.
layer.setRenderer(symbologyLayer.renderer().clone())

